# User friendly password reset tool

Tags: active-directory, password, windows

I need a user friendly way for non-technical people to reset another persons password in Active Directory.

The use case for this is a school where the lab supervisors need the ability to reset a students password without involoving the already overburdened IT staff.

The requirements:
 - I can't have them going into AD Users and Computers or using a command line.
 - If the username is entered by selecting from a list, it should only list users in a subset of OUs, and the OU configuration should not be visible to the end user.

Is there a tool like this that exists.

Comment: Could I ask why you're ruling out ADUC? If you grant only the necessary permissions on AD objects/attributes, they won't be able to do any damage and it's a pretty simple, straight-forward interface.

Comment: @ErikA We tried ADUC. It's a simple, straight-forward interface for people on this site, not for your average lab tech.

Comment: At my $WORK, we teach normal, very much non-technical office admin assistants to use ADUC for various tasks. I'd question if these folks are really up to the task of supervising a lab if they're not able to grok ADUC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a tool called [Password Control](http://www.wisesoft.co.uk/software/passwordcontrol/default.aspx), by WiseSoft. It works very well and is easy for users to understand. It has a configuration file that you can modify to enable/disable various GUI controls and default values. It obviously requires the proper delegation permissions that ADUC would require, but it's simpler for a non-technical user to grasp.

I believe it meets your second criteria by requiring entering the username and does not allow selecting from a list. I don't recall exactly, as I haven't had to assist anyone after initially training people.

Answer (score 2):

If you or someone on the I.T. staff can build asp.net apps, you can build a relatively straightforward [website](http://www.primaryobjects.com/CMS/Article66.aspx) for the lab supervisors to use in resetting passwords.  You can also visit [here](http://www.asp.net/search?q=active+directory+ldap+user+change&page=1&searchtab=Forums).

ManageEngine also makes some pretty useful tools. You might take a look at their [ADSelfService Plus](http://www.manageengine.com/products/self-service-password/active-directory-change-password.html) software.

But really, I'd have to agree with most everyone else.  How hard can it be to right-click a user name and reset password? o_O

[image]

[image]